# Routing to Controller with Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have the following form in my _partial.cshtml:

```
<form class="form-inline text-center" asp-controller="Search" asp-action="Index">
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => new Search().SearchTerm, new { @class = "form-control search-term-box", placeholder = "Search keyword" })
       <span class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1 ml-1">Near</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => new Search().Location, new { @class = "form-control search-term-box mr-2", placeholder = "Los Angeles, CA" })
   <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
   </form>
```

My SearchController.cs:

```
        [BindProperty]
        public Search SearchModel { get; set; }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Search term, Search location = null)
        {
            SearchModel = new Search()
            {
                SearchTerm = term.ToString(),
                Location = location.ToString()
            };

            //(Razor) Search Page with no page model
            //Bind SearchModel to page
            return View("Search");
        }
```

In ASP.Net MVC, I can do something like this and it would work fine, but how do I get this to work with with ASP.Net Core Razor Pages? Clicking the submit button does nothing. If it matters in my Startup.cs, I have `services.AddMvc(o => o.EnabledEndpointRouting = false);` under ConfigureServices method and `app.UseMvc();` under Configure method. I am new to Razor Pages, so if there is a better convention of achieving the same please advice.

Edit: I have found the solution, I added a routing attribute to my search controller. Although its a suitable solution, I essentially applied the MVC convention to my project which is made up of Razor Pages. If anyone can provide a solution that applies to Razor Pages, answers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

By default razor pages need are located under root folder and its default naming convention is '/Pages'. you can find that in startup.cs file . Change the folder name to your desired project folder name as 'xyz' and then try to navigate your page as controllername/index.cshtml . Dont forget to add extension as .cshtml

Comment: Although, you may be right, its not the solution I was looking for. In my situation, I don't want to change the default convention. I have a Pages folder and created some razor pages. Anyway, I fixed the problem by adding a routing attribute to my search controller.